# Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcuts

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 with the MATE desktop. Recently, after a regular upgrade, I found I could no longer launch Keyboard Shortcuts from the system's Preferences menu. The applet just won't launch. Is there any way I can re-install this applet or bring it back to life? Thank you. PA

Comment: The `sudo apt install --reinstall mate-control-center mate-control-center-common` should fix the issue. Do you have any error output if you run it manually from terminal by `mate-keybinding-properties` and/or `mate-keyboard-properties`?

Comment: Tried all of the above but without success. Commands not accepted as valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "Commands not accepted as valid."? Please add terminal commands entered and error output to the question.